# SQL Update Based on Multi-Table Computed Values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL statement that will be run daily against my db; logically, it will set a value on one table to null after a period of time has elapsed. However, determining whether that period has passed requires examining two other tables and then calculating the length of time that has passed based on the values contained therein.

My current SQL statement works for these purposes (see below) but as it relies on the use of an IN clause, there's the possibility it'll run afoul of the 1000 element limit that applies to IN clauses. I'd like to reformat this query away from relying on an IN so that it doesn't matter how many records this update is touching.

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.field1 = null
WHERE table1.table1_id IN
(SELECT table1_id
 FROM (SELECT table1_id, (SYSDATE - MAX(table2.date_field)) days
       WHERE table1.field1 IS NOT null
       AND table1.table1_id = table2.table1_fk
       AND table2.table3_fk = table3.table3_id
       AND (table3.type = X OR table3.type = Y)
       GROUP BY table1_id) tmp_table
 WHERE days >= cutoff)
```

How can this be rewritten such that field1 of table1 is set appropriately to null without relying on the potentially fallible IN clause? This is an Oracle db, to whatever extent that effects the possible solutions.

Comment: What do you mean "run afoul of the 1000 element limit"? Does your inner query return expected results?

Comment: As part of a different query, I recently found out oracle caps the number of elements in an IN clause to 1000, and throws an exception when that's exceeded. It seems unlikely, but if there were a large number of records that ticked over at the same time, the IN clause could possibly trip that limit? I'm not entirely sure if it applies to a sub-query vs a straight list of values, but it's something I'm trying to stay aware of now.

Comment: Oracle does not have such limits. It seems there was a problem with the query that threw an exception.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov ORA-01795!!!

Comment: @hbourchi, that is not subquery limits. It's the max size of simple values, like `in ('value1', 'value2', 'value3'...'value1000')`

Comment: @PavelSmirnov. Sorry! you are right. I didn't pay attention to the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question fully but another way to write your query is using EXISTS. something like this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.field1 = null
WHERE exists 
(SELECT null
 FROM (SELECT table1_id, (SYSDATE - MAX(table2.date_field)) days
       WHERE table1.field1 IS NOT null
       AND table1.table1_id = table2.table1_fk
       AND table2.table3_fk = table3.table3_id
       AND (table3.type = X OR table3.type = Y)
       GROUP BY table1_id) tmp_table
WHERE days >= cutoff
and table1.table1_id = tmp_table.table1_id)
```

Comment: The sub-sub query is missing a FROM statement, and I changed the SELECT null to SELECT table1.table1_id, but this seems to work! I figured it was going to be something simple, thanks for this.